# Webpack config script is not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, media

I'm using webpack config for my react.js application. When i run the command `npm run build` my images and font files are not build under media directory as i defined in my webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['./app/main.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader'
      },
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
          plugins: [
            'transform-runtime',
            'transform-object-rest-spread'
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf|png|jpg|gif)([\?]?.*)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'media/[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      { // Load JSON-files into code base.
        test: /\.json$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'json',
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: getPlugins(),
  devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

But the files are placed just inside my dist. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

That is the right behaviour. webpack outputs everything fist for your output path, then from that it starts to create folders for loaders. You can't have javascript under `/dist` and force it to output all other files to `/media`. It is always going to be everything under your dist.